# Is it possible to maintain UIButtons across multiple views?

Tags: uibutton, uitabbar

Is it possible to maintain the display and update of UIButtons across multiple views in a UITabBar on the iPhone?

I have several UIbuttons that updated continually (e.g. a countdown timer, a current time display) that I want to continually display while allowing the user to switch between different views using a UITabBar.  Am I making this more difficult than it seems?  A UITabBarController in a UINavigationController?  Doesn't appear to be permitted.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible but you can make different buttons for each view and then have them all call apron the same selector with an id of who the call came from...hope that helps. 
I'm running into the same problem.